# devise_invitable not able to accept invitations anymore (but works via console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2, devise-invitable

I am using `devise_invitable` to create guest accounts to access a document. When accessing a document, a guest can click on an upgrade button that will upgrade to a full account. Clicking on the upgrade button is accepting `devise_invitable` invitation.

Was previously working: no longer working.

Environment:

- rails 4.2.3 (recently upgraded)
- devise 3.4.1
- devise_invitable 1.3.6

I use a header partial for a guest user that generates an upgrade link:

```
<% @invite_link = accept_user_invitation_url(invitation_token: @invite_token) %>
<%= link_to "Upgrade", @invite_link, class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" %>
```

`@invite_token` is created like:

```
user = current_user
user.invite! do |u|
  u.skip_invitation = true
end
@invite_token = user.raw_invitation_token
```

So `link_to` helper generates something like: `https://myapp/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=vv_JqeFDLfyX65tx2KhR`

Except when I click on the link, it takes me to: `https://myapp/users/sign_in`

With error message: `The invitation token provided is not valid!`

Log reports something like:

```
Started GET "/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=vv_JqeFDLfyX65tx2KhR" for 31.15.32.222 at 2015-10-15 19:18:34 +1100
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"invitation_token"=>"vv_JqeFDLfyX65tx2KhR"}
  User Load (5.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["invitation_token", "ea9be9890c684e13ece13ec02f89bade81fcd3ac1fb982db72d8f8561d0cf289"]]
Redirected to https://myapp/
Filter chain halted as :resource_from_invitation_token rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 53ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
Started GET "/" for 31.15.32.222 at 2015-10-15 19:49:52 +1100
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
Redirected to https://myapp/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Am able to make this work via rails console.**

If I run rails console in parallel, I am able to step through the above steps and generate an accept_invitation link that works as expected (i.e. it prompts user to set a password for the full account).

NB: the `raw_invitation_token` is different in the rails console session.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found code that called `user.invite!` to generate `raw_invitation_token` **when page was displayed** and **after** the accept_invitation link was generated. This meant that the token in the accept_invitation link was now outdated.

Going via the console, this code was not called as no controller, view or javascript components are invoked. So when using the console, things worked as expected.

Fixed and all back to normal.